# jQuery selector with slashes

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have html

```
<a href="#" data-ext="sql" rel="\dir\file.sql" id="file">file.sql</a>
```

And i want find this `a#file` among others by `rel`, so

```
$("#file[rel='\dir\file.sql']")
```

not works, because `\` removing (why?)

```
var some_var = "/s/s/s/\a\a\a";
// undefined
some_var
// "/s/s/s/aaa"
```

So, how i can select item(items) by rel with `\` in it?

And this is not all want to work

```
$("#file[rel='\\dir\\file.sql']")
$("#file[rel='/\dir/\file.sql']")  // ^^
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/fUNLV/1/ not works :(

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash is an escape character. To escape the escape character, you can double it up:

Edit - In this case, the escaping needs to be double-escaped:

http://jsfiddle.net/FSqZe/

```
var $el = $('#file[rel="\\\\dir\\\\file.sql"]');
```

Comment: Because it gets unescaped twice.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double backslashed for this:

```
$("#file[rel='\\dir\\file.sql']")
```

This happens because just one `\` slash will try to escape next symbol and double slashes will escape first slash.

**UPDATE**

Seems you need to use `\\\\`:

```
$("#file[rel='\\\\dir\\\\file.sql']")
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fUNLV/3/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape both slashes, not just 1.

```
$("#file[rel='\\\\dir\\\\file.sql']") // that's 4 slashes in each case, 8 total
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/fUNLV/2/

This is because First, this string is passed to jQuery, at which point it would become

```
"#file[rel='\\dir\\file.sql']"
```

then when it gets passed again internally to `document.querySelectorAll()`, the slashes are correctly escaped for the css selector engine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/fUNLV/4/

Comment: I've never come across it myself, but i've come across it once before here on SO.